# navigation bar possibly causing UIView offset

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller that consists of two `UIViews`.  One view is the super view and the other is a subview.  Both views are the same size 320X568 and have the same origin (0,0).  I added constraints to the subview by first setting an aspect ratio to itself, then an equal width ratio to the superview with a multiplier of 1.  I then centered the subview horizontally and vertically in the container.  When an up drag gesture is recognized, the subview is suppose to move up a certain amount using `CGRectOffset`.  I noticed that the view wasn't ending in the right position, so I removed all the offset code to see what was going on.  In `viewDidLoad` I check the origin.y of both the super view and subview and its 0 - which is correct.  However, once the up drag gesture is recognized, I do another `NSLog` for the y origins and the subview prints -31.5 and the superview prints 64.  Not sure how this is happening with all the `CGRectOffset` commented out.  I'm thinking this might have to do with the navigation bar but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the deal is with the CGRectOffset, but I do know what the "problem" is without it. There's no problem! The only thing here is that you are checking the `origin.y` of the views *too soon*, namely in `viewDidLoad`.

Remember, in `viewDidLoad` nothing has actually happened yet. The view controller *has* a view but that's all. In particular, the view is *not yet in the interface* and has *not been given its layout yet*.

So it's really just a matter of knowing what the events mean. You're assuming that `viewDidLoad` means the view is in the interface and has its position and size. It doesn't mean anything like that. If you want to know what the view's position is after layout, you need to wait until after layout. Like, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a good place. It means that layout has just occurred!

As for the 64 value, it's just what you would expect. You have pinned your view's top to the top layout guide - which means the bottom of the navigation bar, exactly as you have suggested.

Comment: Makes sense.  I understand why the superview has an origin.y of 64, but why does the subview have an origin of -32.

Comment: I can't magically see into your storyboard, so don't know how it is laid out by its constraints. But that's the result; it's that way because that's how you set it up, that's all I can tell you.

Comment: So after `viewDidLoad` the superview origin is at 64 with a height of 504 - makes sense.  For the subview, I set its vertical space to the top layout guide with a constant of -64.  Now its position and height are -64 and 568.  I'm kind of confused where the origin.y is suppose to be with the navigation bar present.

Comment: Well, think about it. -64 with respect to the top layout guide means 64 _higher_ than the top layout guide. The top layout guide is the _bottom_ of the navigation bar. So you are positioning the top of the subview up behind the navigation bar. Meanwhile, the top of the superview is _at_ the top layout guide. The position (`frame`) of the subview is measured in superview coordinates, so that's why its origin.y is -64 - it is 64 points higher than the top of its superview. What you get is what you ask for.

Comment: So since the superview has a origin.y of 64, for the subview thats actually y=0.  So since my subview origin.y =-64, thats actually superview.origin.y - 64 = 0 which is origin.y of the window.  Is that right?

Comment: You are tossing the term `origin.y` around but you are using it in different ways. The subview's position in its superview is its `frame` and is measured in terms of its superview's coordinates. Its superview's coordinates are its `bounds`. Then the superview too has a `frame` which is measured with respect to _its_ superview's `bounds`. It happens that by default a view's bounds origin is its own top left corner. See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame

Comment: Do you realize that I haven't the slightest idea where you actually _want_ the subview to end up? Why don't you actually _say_ where you want it and _ask_ how to position it there?

Comment: I just want the subview and superview to have the same position (0,0) and the same size.

Comment: Then pin the top of the subview _to the top of the superview_. Not to the top layout guide.

Comment: I forgot about that.  I've been doing the control drag between the subview and superview so that option never appears.  I see that the size of my subview is 568 while that superview is 504.  So does that mean the bottom 64px of my subview are hanging off the bottom?

Comment: That depends where the top of the subview is in relation to the superview, doesn't it? But if you pin the top of the subview to the top of the superview (constant 0) and the bottom of the subview to the bottom of the superview (constant 0) then that can't happen, can it?

Comment: Well if you pin the subview to the top space of the superview without pinning the bottom, isn't that what happens?  The bottom 64px of the subview wont' be  visible.

Comment: Also, if you pin to the top and bottom of the superview you get a warning saying "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

Comment: But that's because of certain other constraints you've already added. You need to remove those.

Comment: Instead of just thrashing about, why don't you _learn_ about constraints? They really make perfect sense, you know.